# How use scroll down itemlabel a click and item is addClass active jquery please help me

Tags: jquery, css

// When i am click a and item is acitve and scroll but i cant do how use jquery. i am very tired..
i want item addClass active scrolldown and removeClass active a when i click  anchor..

```
 <div class="itemlabel">
    <a href="#select1">1</a>
    <a href="#select2">2</a>
    <a href="#select3">3</a>
    <a href="#select4">4</a>
    <a href="#select5">5</a>
    <a href="#select6">6</a>
    <a href="#select7">7</a>
    <a href="#select8">8</a>                    
</div>

 <div class="item active">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select1">1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select2">2</div>
 </div>

 <div class="item">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select3">3</div>
 </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select4">4</div>
   </div>
 <div class="item">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select5">5</div>
</div>
 <div class="item">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select6">6</div>
</div>
 <div class="item">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select7">8</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="xx">
    <span> teest</span>
    <div class="lablecircle" id="select8">8</div>
</div>
```

// css

```
   .item{
        position:relative;
        height:300px;
        width:45%;
        border:1px solid #ddd;
    }
     .itemlabel{
        margin-bottom:50px;
      }

    .itemlabel a{
              font-size:14px;
           color:#fff;
           width:40px;
           height:40px;
           line-height:40px;
           display:inline-block;
           border-radius: 50%;
           background-color:#999;
           text-decoration:none;
          font-weight:bold;
    }
```

// jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".itemlabel a").on("click" ,function(){
     $('.lablecircle').parent().addClass("active");
        //how use itemdown scroll jquery
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aungnyeinmin/D7wab/

Comment: i want item addClass active scrolldown and removeClass active a when i click  anchor..

Answer (score 0):

i want item addClass active scrolldown and removeClass active a when i click anchor.